# Does System.Data.SQLite Support the Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I was wondering if the most recent versions of System.Data.SQLite support the compact framework. In the release notes it mentions:

> "Compact framework not currently not
>   included. We hope to have this feature
>   included again soon."

It appears that version 1.0.66.0 does not have this in the release notes but versions like 1.0.69.0 or 1.0.72.0 do. I'm not really sure what they mean by not included but oddly enough they have .csproj files for a Compact build which would seem to indicate they do support it.

If no one knows for sure if it supports it or not is there a good way to test?

Thanks!

Comment: I would pull down the source, build it locally, and then try the resulting DLL. If everything works, you're good to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull down an [older version](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/readme.htm), e.g. 1.0.66.0 and it's all good.  It just appears to be some teething trouble whilst the project shifts to its new home.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.

Get the latest version from this website:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/features.wiki